# Memory Leak using numpy linalg in parallel

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, parallel-processing, least-squares, joblib

I have the below code to run least square on each row of a matrix U.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm,lstsq
from sklearn.externals.joblib import Parallel,delayed
k = 25
max_iter = 50
lmbda = 1e-3
R = np.random.randint(0,2,(1500,2500))
W = np.sign(R,dtype=np.int8)
rows, columns = R.shape
random = np.random.RandomState(seed=4)
U = np.zeros((rows,k),dtype=np.float32)
V = random.rand(columns,k).astype(np.float32)
D = random.rand(columns,k).astype(np.float32)
S = random.rand(columns,columns).astype(np.float32)
S = (S + S.T)/2
Ir = np.eye(k,dtype=np.int8)
for i in xrange(1,max_iter+1):
    U = Parallel(n_jobs=5)(delayed(lstsq)(np.dot(V.T,np.dot(np.diag(Wu),V))+lmbda*Ir, np.dot(R[u],np.dot(np.diag(Wu),V)),rcond=None) for u,Wu in enumerate(W))
    U = np.vstack([u[0] for u in U])
    V = Parallel(n_jobs=5)(delayed(lstsq)(np.dot(U.T,np.dot(np.diag(Wv),U))+np.dot(D.T,D), np.dot(S[v],D)+np.dot(R.T[v],np.dot(np.diag(Wv),U)),rcond=None) for v,Wv in enumerate(W.T))
    V = np.vstack([v[0] for v in V])
```

But whatever be the n_jobs value I set, I get the below error

> local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py:700:
>   UserWarning: A worker stopped while some jobs were given to the
>   executor. This can be caused by a too short worker timeout or by a
>   memory leak.   "timeout or by a memory leak.", UserWarning

It seems the exact error is caused by the vstack function trying to run before the parallel operation finished.  But for large n_jobs (=15), even the lstsq function was also giving memory leak warning.  I have been stuck with this for a week now.